# How to catch an exception thrown by a function?

Tags: java, ioexception

My function has thrown an `IOException` of the following format. How do I catch an exception written like this, I've used the standard try/catch blocks.

```
public static void loader(int[] arr, String file) throws IOException
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    for(int i = 0; sc.hasNextInt(16) ; ++i)
        arr[i] = sc.nextInt(16);
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about "the standard try and except blocks" as in Python?

Comment: Just surround your call to loader() with a try/catch as usual.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a checked `Exception` in the signature of a method, you don't need to handle it in this method. At the contrary, any method calling `loader` will have either to declare this `Exception` in its header or handling it in a try/catch block :

```
public void someMethod() throws IOException {
   loader(...);
}

// or

public void someMethod() {
   try {
     loader(...);
   } catch (IOException io) {
      //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
//method call
}
catch (IOException e) {
//handle Exception
}
```

Or by using try with resources if class that declares the method implements `AutoClosable` interface

Comment: ok, what's wrong with my answer? I like when someone downvotes without leaving comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just fill your code with a try/catch method:

Like this:

```
public static void loader(int[] arr, String file) throws IOException
{

try{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    for(int i = 0; sc.hasNextInt(16) ; ++i)
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt(16);
}catch(IOException e) {
//Do whatever you want with the exception
}
```

}

Comment: I have just replaced the word Exception for IOException, that is it.

Comment: So what else do you need? there you are only catching an IOException, isn't this what you want to do? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method, as it is, just punts the `IOException` to the next method on the call stack. In that case, your calling code would need to handle the exception:

```
public void foo() {
    // assuming your method is in the Bar class
    int[] secretCodes = {};
    try {
        Bar.loader(secretCodes, new File("C:\\tmp.txt");
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To use a try/catch block, though, you should remove the `IOException` from the method signature. Then, you would no longer need to have the code that calls your method include a try/catch block.

In this case, your code would look like this:

```
public static void loader(int[] arr, String file)
{
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        for(int i = 0; sc.hasNextInt(16) ; ++i)
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt(16);
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); // Or however you want to handle the exception
    }
}
```

Note that you no longer need a `throws IOException` in the method signature, since it's already handled in the method. (Unless, of course, your method throws one *outside* the try block.)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. Handle the exception in the calling code:

   ```
   try {
       YourClass.loader(/*...relevant args...*/);
   }
   catch (IOException ioe) {
       // ...do something with `ioe`...
   }
   ```

   or,
2. Handle the exception *inside* the method:

   ```
   public static void loader(int[] arr, String file)
   {
       try {
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
           for(int i = 0; sc.hasNextInt(16) ; ++i)
               arr[i] = sc.nextInt(16);
       }
       catch (IO Exception ioe) {
           /*...do something with `ioe`....*/
       }
   }
   ```

Which you choose is up to you. It's frequently useful to handle exceptions at an outer level (#1), but it totally depends on the code and context.